# Static link intel CRT

Tags: c, visual-studio, intel

I am compiling a C code using the intel compiler. I integrated icc with visual studio 2010. I want to generate an optimized executable which will run on a windows machine. It is actually a virtual machine in the cloud. I don't have a chance to install any redistributable library to the target machine. I want to statically link all the required libraries. How can I do this?

Comment: `-static` command line option - doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you meant icl since you're mentioning VS2010/Windows (icc would be Linux/Mac version): just selecting 'Multi-threaded (/MT)' under Project settings->Configuration properties->C/C++->Code Generation should work. It'll cause both MSVC and Intel runtime to be statically linked into app.

But then it also depends which other libraries are you using, it might not work for all. In that case you can check the dependencies with depends.exe (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and copy them side-by-side with your .exe to target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-i-static -static-libcxa` to the final linkage.

This should force static linking for intel libraries only.

(You can also try `-static` as littleadv suggested in the comment, but this will produce a huge static executable with no shared libraries at all)

One more note: A simple workaround would be to copy the executable with the required shared libraries (those that do not exist at the host) to the same directory. Then set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` before running your dynamically linked executable. This will force searching for libraries in the current directory as well as system directories.

EDIT: I just noticed you said "windows machine". The above is relevant to UNIX machines so probably not useful to you. I'll leave it here in case someone needs the information.